# Settimeout not clearing in react hooks- function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I've trying to implement simple updates in a function component in react and seem to have stumbled onto some basic logical errors on my part. Can you help?

My code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

var timeout;  // this variable wasn't scoped inside the function?.

function App() {
  const [name, setUserName] = useState("");

  const [password, setUserPassword] = useState("");

  const [showHackMessage, setShowHackMessage] = useState(false);

  const enterUserName = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setUserName(e.target.value);
  };

  const enterUserPassword = (e) => {

    console.log(e.target.value,timeout);
    setUserPassword(e.target.value);
    if (e.target.value.length > 0) {
      timeout= setTimeout(()=>setShowHackMessage(true), 1000);
      console.log(timeout);

      /// Why did not  timeout= setTimeout(setShowHackMessage(true), 5000); work? is  setShowHackMessage not a function?
      //  timeout();
    } 
    else if(e.target.value.length===0) {
      console.log("Tricky user!");
      console.log(timeout,'L29>>');
      //not working perfectly!
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      setShowHackMessage(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Login-Hacker</p>
      <input name={"email"} onChange={enterUserName}></input>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>

      <input name={"password"} onChange={(e)=>enterUserPassword(e)}></input>
      <p>Powered by Saurabh</p>
      {name.length > 0 && <p>Your name is {name}</p>}
      {password.length > 0 && <p>Your password is {password}</p>}
      {showHackMessage && <p className='awesome'>Now you are hacked!</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So my first question would be:-

1. Why do i have to use callback while defining a setstate function in settimeout? 
   I tried

   timeout= setTimeout(setShowHackMessage(true), 1000);
    and it didn't work, while

   timeout= setTimeout(()=>setShowHackMessage(true), 1000);
   works perfectly. Is setShowHackMessage (in useState not a function?)
2. If i define the variable var timeout inside the function, the cleartimeout doesn't work(shows as undefined in console), but works perfectly if i define it outside the function, as in the code. Is the whole function "rendered" after setstate( hence losing previous instance of variable timeout?).Should i have used refs for this?

   Thank you.

Comment: use `useEffect` for that  ... 1) you already called func, not defined func to be called

Comment: First, describe what you want to achieve...

Comment: try using useRef() . useRef is used to mimic instance variables. Component doesnot rerender when it's value is changed

Comment: It seems useRef() is the way to go for holding the id of returned after setimeout. I don't see how useEffect would be helpful here though @xadm.

Comment: `useEffect` has clearing mechanism

Comment: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/ - useEffect inside ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is a simpler version. I removed the `timeout` variable as I don't see why you use it.

```
        import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
// import "./App.css";

// let timeout;  // this variable wasn't scoped inside the function?.
const EMPTY_STRING = "";

function App() {
const [name, setUserName] = useState("");
const [password, setUserPassword] = useState("");
const [showHackMessage, setShowHackMessage] = useState(false);
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

const enterUserName = useCallback(
    value => {
    console.log(value);
    setUserName(value);
    },
    [setUserName]
);

const enterUserPassword = useCallback(
    value => {
    setShowHackMessage(false);
    setUserPassword(value);
    console.log("password value", value);
    if (timer) {
        console.log("clear Timer=>", timer);
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    if (value !== EMPTY_STRING) {
        setTimer(setTimeout(() => setShowHackMessage(true), 5000));
        console.log("set Timer=>", timer);
    }
    console.log("password", password);
    },
    [setUserPassword, setShowHackMessage, password, timer]
);

return (
    <div className="App">
    <p>Login-Hacker</p>
    <input
        name={"email"}
        value={name}
        onChange={e => enterUserName(e.target.value)}
    />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input
        name={"password"}
        value={password}
        onChange={e => enterUserPassword(e.target.value)}
    />
    <p>Powered by Saurabh</p>
    {name.length > 0 && <p>Your name is {name}</p>}
    {password.length > 0 && <p>Your password is {password}</p>}
    {showHackMessage && <p className="awesome">Now you are hacked!</p>}
    </div>
);
}

export default App;
```

[image: Edit affectionate-jennings-htolo]

Comment: I am really sorry for not stating the purpose of using settimeout . I wanted to show the message "You are hacked", after an interval of 5 second of entering the password(so the setstate should have occured 5 seconds after the password was typed, and timeout should've cleared if user erased the password before 5 seconds). Sorry if the code seems funny, i was experimenting it was best i could come up with at the time. Thanks.

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I understand now. I updated the code !

Comment: useEffect should be used for clearing interval on unmount